# Why Google Plus load CSS with XHR and append it to a <style> instead using <link>?

Tags: javascript, css, google-plus

Analyzing the new Google Plus's javascripts, I realized that Google Plus instead of using `<link>` to reference a CSS file, it uses XHR to load it from a file, then creates a `<style>` and then loads the CSS content to `<style>`.

What is the reason that Google uses this method to load the CSS?

**Proof:**

```
D = function(a) {
  var b = document.createElement("style");
  b.type = "text/css";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(b);
  b.styleSheet ? b.styleSheet.cssText = a : b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a))
};

var ia = function(a, b) {
  if(4 == b.readyState) {
    var d = window;
    $("xcl");
    b.onreadystatechange = k;
    var c = b.status;
    if(400 > c) {
      try {
        var e = b.getResponseHeader("X-Framework-CSS-Blocks"), f = b.responseText;
        if(e) {
          for(var e = e.split(","), g = c = 0;g < e.length;g++) {
            var V = Number(e[g]);
            D(f.substr(c, V));
            c += V
          }
          c < f.length && D(f.substr(c))
        }else {
          D(f), ha() && C("css", a, d.OZ_lang, "nooffsets")
        }
        d.setTimeout(function() {
          for(var b = i, c = 0, e = document.styleSheets.length;c < e;c++) {
            var g = document.styleSheets[c], g = g.cssRules || g.rules;
            0 < g.length && "sentinel" == g[g.length - 1].selectorText && (b = !0)
          }
          b || C("css", a, d.OZ_lang, "truncated." + f.length)
        }, 1E3)
      }catch(W) {
        throw d.console && d.console.warn(W), C("css", a, d.OZ_lang, "error"), W;
      }
    }else {
      C("css", a, d.OZ_lang, "status." + c)
    }
    $("xcr")
  }
}, ja = function() {
  var a = window.OZ_cssUrl;
  $("xcs");
  var b = ga();
  b.open("GET", a, !0);
  b.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ia(a, b)
  };
  b.send(h)
}

window.OZ_cssUrl && ja()
```

Comment: My guess is that this allows them to quickly make changes to the CSS without having to worry about the styles being cached. It'll use more bandwidth though. Also using XHR to download the styles lets them dynamically add styles to the page.

Comment: @sissonb: caching can and should be handled via HTTP headers

Comment: @sissonb I thought that too, but the CSS file specify a date for the cache and when I surf for the second time, Google Chrome loads it from cache...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer given by Mark Knichel, an engineer on the Google+ infrastructure team.

"you may have noticed that we load our CSS via a XHR instead of a style tag - that is not for optimization reasons, that’s because we hit Internet Explorer’s max CSS selector limit per stylesheet!"

Read the whole thing at https://plus.google.com/u/0/115060278409766341143/posts/ViaVbBMpSVG

Answer (score 6):

Loading CSS via dynamic link tags are unreliable as link tags don't have consistent browser support for [load](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html) and [error](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html) events. Dynamic link tags does work but you don't know if and when the CSS loaded. Plus the fact that they are async, you don't know which came in first and you might end up with the wrong style cascade order.

Instead, it loads it via AJAX as a string, since AJAX has a reliable success and fail events. Then when the string is received, you then append it to a style tag. Since you know the events, you know which came in and which ones did not.

This sacrifices cross-domain CSS for the ability to know if and when the CSS loads.

Comment: Good point, but I think it also can be detected the sucess and failure creating a `<link>` with javascript and using `onload` event. And about the cascade order, the Google Plus's javascript use async XHR to load the CSS too...

Comment: @Fong-WanChau events are inconsistent using the link tags, see the links i provided. That's the reason why dynamic CSS uses XHR instead.

Answer (score 2):

Regard this there have been current developments where a google developer reported a huge performance gain by switching away from XHR to normal `<link>` inclusion.

> In SPDY capable browsers this resulted in a big latency improvement. In Chrome 27 we saw a 4x speedup at the median, and 5x at 25th percentile. In Firefox 21 we saw a 5x speedup at median, and 8x at 25th percentile. No significant impact was seen at the 99th percentile.

Source: https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/G6W7XVHXiED